# Autolayout のベストプラクティスを知りたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, autolayout

Objective-C で iOS アプリ作成の勉強をしている学生です。
未熟ゆえ語弊があったり、勘違いがあったりで至らぬ質問かもしれませんが、回答していただけますと幸いです。

全ての iPhone 、 iPad の画面サイズに対応させるアプリを作る場合、どのように作成するのがベターと言いますか効率が良いでしょうか。
また、 Autolayout は万能なのでしょうか？

この質問のきっかけは、自分なりに Autolayout を勉強して、 View(IB) の並びが複雑な画面に色々制約を加えて試行錯誤しても思い通りの配置にできなかったからです。
というのも 4inch , 4.7inch に対応できても 5.5inch でズレていたり、元の `UIImageView` の素材画像にも手を加える必要が出てきたり？と問題が発生しました。
 iPad 用と iPhone 用に Storyboard を使い分ける作りならまだしも、 4inch+4.7inch 用、5.5inch 用の Autolayout 設定など解決策に考えましたが、非常に効率の悪い作りに感じました。

Autolayout 自体、ケースバイケースなものなら良いのですが、もし Autolayout が万能な(適切に設定することであらゆる画面に対応できる)ものだとして、自分が使いこなせていないだけなら非常に効率が悪いことを続けることになるのでそれだけは避けたいと思い、鉄板な方法といいますか、可能であればプロがやっている方法？意見( Autolayout をどう活用しているのかなど)を聞きたいと思いました。

そんな感じで Autolayout についてネット上で色々調べたのですが、 Universalアプリ作成に対する自分の結論が出せずとても困っています。
ご回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こういう漠然とした質問には、回答しづらいですね。ユニバーサルAppといっても、iOS8以降だけを対象とするのか、iOS6,7を対象とするのかで、大変ちがいますから。iOS6,7,8を対象とするユニバーサルAppを、SDK8を使ってビルドするのは、ほぼ、無理というか、大変なんじゃないでしょうか。というのも、iOS8と、以前では、異なる部分がかなりあるからです。
　iOS8だけなら、WWDC2014のAdaptive UI のセッション見た方がいいでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

ケースバイケースとしか言いようないですが、個人的にはstroyboardを使用せず、Autolayoutも極力使わず、基本は位置やサイズは比率によって計算して、コードで書くようにしています。そのほうが、計算が楽なのと、ソースコードに統一させることで管理が楽になります。

ただアプリの構成によりけりなので、何が正しいかという問題ではないと思いますので、ご自身で学習し、都度判断されるのが良いと思います。